# Is it possible to declare multiple static variables with same name in a single C file?

Tags: c, static

Is it possible to declare multiple static variables of same name in a single C file with different scopes?
I wrote a simple programme to check this and in gcc it got compiled and worked fine.

Code:

```
static int sVar = 44;

void myPrint2()
{
    printf("sVar = %d\n", sVar++);
}

void myPrint()
{
    static int sVar =88;
    printf("sVar = %d\n", sVar++);
}

int main(void)
{
    static int sVar = 55;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        myPrint();      
    printf("sVar = %d\n", sVar);
    myPrint2();
    return(0);
}
```

Now my question is since all "static" variable will reside in same section (.data) then how we can have multiple variables with same name in one section?

I used `objdump` to check the different section and found that all the static variables (`sVar`) were in .data section but with different names:

```
0804960c l     O .data  00000004              sVar
08049610 l     O .data  00000004              sVar.1785
08049614 l     O .data  00000004              sVar.1792
```

Why is the compiler is changing the name of the variables (since C doesn't support name mangling)?

Comment: They're just temporary, internal names. Name mangling in C++ applies to things like DLL exports. It's a different thing.

Comment: C allows name mangling, and you've just shown it.

Comment: Name mangling is an implementation detail.  C does not "allow" it as such, it uses it to implement a feature (apparently - I didn't know you could do this, but you learn something new every day).  Similarly C++ does not "allow" name mangling, it uses it to implement function overloading.

Comment: Since the static variables in your example are different entities, the C compiler must come up with a solution to translate the name to the correct variable.  You have shown one example.

Comment: @MSalters C allows variable name mangling but not function name mangling. That is the difference C/C++.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer: You may find that the C standard says the same as the C++ standard: nothing. That leaves name mangling as a valid implementation choice. Of course, there's the question why a C implementation would bother, but you could imagine compatibility with another existing popular language on the platform.

Answer (score 23):

A ***function-local static variable*** is something different than a ***global static variable***.
Since there can be as many function-local statics with the same name as you like (provided they are all in different scopes), the compiler might have to change their names internally (incorporating the function's name or the line number or whatever), so that the linker can tell them apart.

Comment: That is true but both local and global static variable are residing in same data section and since you cant have multiple variables of same name in same data sections therefore I believe compiler is changing the name. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: @Mohammed: The way I understand you, you have just repeated my second sentence. Why should I disagree with that? `:)`

Comment: Ya true..:) Is it mean C compile also support name mangling??

Comment: It can mangle the names here (into invalid C names) because it can expect that no other object file will refer to them.  The linker needs them only so that it can resolve the relative memory accesses when the data section is given a fixed address at load time.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between *visibility* and *extent*; also, the `static` keyword has different meanings based on scope.

Adding the `static` keyword to the block scope versions of `sVar` (myPrint::sVar and main::sVar) changes their *extent* (lifetime), but not their visibility; both are visible within their respective functions only, and will shadow or hide the file scope version within their local scope.  It indicates that the variables have static extent, meaning the memory for them is allocated at program start and held until the program terminates (as opposed to automatic or local extent, where their lifetime is limited to the scope in which they are defined).

Adding the `static` keyword to the file scope version of `sVar` doesn't change its extent (file scope variables have static extent by definition), but it does change its visibility with respect to other translation units; the name is not exported to the linker, so it cannot be accessed by name from another translation unit. It is still visible within the current translation unit, which is why myPrint2 can access it.

Comment: I like this answer and I suspect this is actually what the author is confused about.

Answer (score 2):

Your first `sVar` is global to file, second one is local to the function `myPrint()` and third one is local to `main()`

Function level static variables are not accessible outside the function - they just retain their values on subsequent calls. I assume you've already noted this when you ran your code.

Answer (score 1):

Block scoping. Read K & R.

Answer (score 1):

The static keyword has different meanings when it's global and local, the first `sVar` is just a global variable unavailable to other translation units. And static variables `sVar` in `myPrint()` and `main()` are in different scopes, so they are different variables. In the body of `myPrint()` `sVar` refers to the local static (hiding global `sVar`), in `myPrint2()` it refers to the global (it's not hidden by anything local), and in `main()` it refers to the local `static sVar`, which again hides the global since the moment it was declared.

Answer (score 0):

Both function will create different stacks, so static part also will be different 
.Therefore it is possible.

Comment: Neither of the local `static int sVar;` will be allocated on the *stack* (if there is such a concept at all), each function body is a separate block, which limits the scope of the local `static` variable.  The compiler uses a renaming scheme to ensure these variables are distinct at link time.